# Display an image from within web directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using VS 2015 and ASP.net/VB.

On my desktop I am building a web application which is saved on a remote server (development server).  If I run the web site using VS then everything works fine.

I want to demo the web application to a user and I am having an issue with an image on the page.  I am sure there is something easy I am missing but I cant find a solution on line.  When I demo it I use a url to the server (http://DevelopmentServer/myName/website1/default.aspx) where as when I run it on my PC its localhost etc.

Within the page I have an upload file control which the user can use to upload an image.  Once done the image is displayed on the screen.  The problem I am having is with the file paths.  To upload the image I am using the following code.

```
Protected Sub upLoadFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(chartUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim folderPath As String = "\\developmentServer\website1\charts\"
    Dim fileName As String = "Chart_" & Date.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
    Dim updatedFilename As String = fileName & fileExt

    chartUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folderPath & updatedFilename))
    displayCurrentChart()

End Sub
```

The above works fine when using the url - http://DevelopmentServer/myName/website1/default.aspx

The problem occurs when I want to display the image using the following code:

```
Private Sub displayCurrentChart()

    Dim chartName As String = "Chart_" & Date.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") & ".jpg"
    Dim folderPath As String = "D:\Developement\Website1\charts\"
    Dim fullFilePath As String = folderPath & chartName
    chartImage.Visible = False

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fullFilePath) Then

        chartImage.ImageUrl = fullFilePath
        chartImage.Visible = True

    Else

        'do nothing

    End If

End Sub
```

I just get a black cross.  I am convinced its to do with the path I am using as obviously the user doesn't have a D drive but it also doesn't work if I use the UNC path of

`\\developmentServer\website1\charts\`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Some problems/suggestions with your code that might cause issues:

- When saving you save the file with the extension the user has suplied, but when displaying you're assuming it is ".jpg"
- `Path.Combine(folderPath & updatedFilename)` should be `Path.Combine(folderPath, updatedFilename)`
- Use [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to get the right path e.g. `Server.MapPath("/charts")` if `/charts` is in the root of your web application

I suggest you set a breakpoint in those methods to see what the actual path is when debugging the application. Then check if the image exists in that path.